# Nginx Rewrite Short URL server in Subfolder URL's only

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

Nginx/Php aficionado's

I have a Yourls install running on Nginx which i've got working fine using the following .conf file. The redirects work, the database is copied over from an apache install and all is fine.

However on the old server I had another simple shortURL service running in a sub directory. It has lots of short URL's created with the style of url.com/p/0aexvibr

They all run in the subdirectory called "p" and all the links look like that, they are plain files with nothing but a URL on the top line.

What I need is for Nginx to redirect urls such as url.com/p/0aexvibr and ignore anything to main the URL that is being redirected by the Yourls rewrite rule below. Take them to a php script in /p/ which then opens and redirects the user the URL in the file linked (in this case 0aexvibr contains the url http://google.com) could someone help set this up?

Current conf

```
server {
listen  80;
server_name url.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
root /var/www/html/url;
charset     utf-8;

 }

location / {

try_files $uri $uri/ /yourls-loader.php;

          index index.php;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;

}

 include     /etc/nginx/drop;

}
```

Here is the contents of the show.php

```
<?php
if($_GET['id']){
    $id = addslashes($_GET['id']);
    if(file_exists("urls/$id"))
    { 
        $url = file_get_contents("urls/$id");
        header("location:".$url); 
    } else {
        echo "Error : invalid hash";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error : no hash";
}
?>
```

Comment: As in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252321/edit-php-script-to-open-url-in-file), you can use an nginx rewrite rule to redirect request to a php script which will open the good url.

Comment: the question is, how, though?

Comment: As you did in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252321/edit-php-script-to-open-url-in-file), do you want to see what's the problem there ?

Comment: Ah, I thought I did it in my other question, but I didn't, it broke the Yourls installation and redirected EVERYTHING to the show.php script. I just wanted to redirect the URLS with /p/ in them.

Comment: Because your nginx rewrite rule should be like this : `rewrite ^p/(.*)$ /dir/show.php?id=$1 last; `.

Comment: Hmm ok, if I try that and put it in my general location block, it just redirects me to the homepage when I try a full url. 

If I try the following code 

    `location /p { 
       if (!-e $request_filename){
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /p/show.php?id=$1 last;
    }`

It redirects to the actual file, but it just downloads the file with the URL in it.

Comment: Could you put your show.php script to see why it downloads the file and not go to redirection ?

Comment: Sure, i've added it to the question so its easier to read - it wasn't download the file previously though, I think thats an nginx rewrite ever, it was loading the shop.php and telling me the hash was invalid, at that point I didnt want it to check I just wanted it to load the URL from the file irregardless

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66058/discussion-between-akmozo-and-realdannys).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how that conf file was working for you , when it comes for the YOURLS redirecting. Anyway, here is my suggestion for your question:

```
server {
listen  80;
server_name url.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
charset     utf-8;


##the next two locations for the old service which calls the show.php
    location ~ ^/p/(.+\.php)$ {
        alias /var/www/html/url/$1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /p {
        alias /var/www/html/url/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /p/show.php;
    }

##the next two locations for the yourls configuration, expecting it to be in the root directory

    location ~ ^/(.+\.php)$ {
        alias /var/www/html/url/$1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        alias /var/www/html/url/;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ yourls-loader.php;
    }

}
```